# Connecting to a device within xcode via bluetooth instead of cabled connector

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth

Idea: Add a device to Xcode without using a cable.

I often find the need to keep my iPhone5 connected while developing an app is a pain because i cannot easily stand it up due to the cable in the bottom. I know i can jury-rig it up, but wondered about using bluetooth connection instead. I tried, but it never seems to work.

Is this possible does anyone know? If so, any explicit tips, pointers, links? I have not found anything yet..